# How can I avoid such weird spaces in a horizontal flexbox gallery?

Tags: css

This is my code:

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  resize: both;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.description {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Wald018.jpg/256px-Wald018.jpg">
    <div class="description">One</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg/256px-Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg">
    <div class="description">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg/297px-Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg">
    <div class="description">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the container size can contain the full width of each item, all spaces between are the same and look the way they should:
[image]

But if not, then for example such stuff can happen:
[image]

In this case, the margins of `.description` get ignored. But this must not happen. The spaces should be calculated like before, the `.description` should keep its space and margin, just the images have to adjust to the container size.

What is the easiest way to fix that? I can't change the complete structure since it's already implemented in a complex website structure. Is there maybe just one flexbox setting that can be used to fix it?

**Addition:** Thanks for the answers. I just realized that the solution doesn't work well for videos. here is what can happen:
[image]
[image]

So the video container is bigger than the video. Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `min-width:0` to the image should fix it

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  resize: both;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item img {
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.description {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Wald018.jpg/256px-Wald018.jpg">
    <div class="description">One</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg/256px-Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg">
    <div class="description">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg/297px-Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg">
    <div class="description">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But now it's not horizontally scrollable anymore. I imagine that just each image fits in the container size proportionally, so it will be visible completely if I scroll to it, but always the width or the height needs to be adjusted to reach that. A bit like the logic of "object-fit: contain;", but for each image in a horizontal scrollable area.

Comment: @Anna_B actually you are describing what your initial code is doing ...

Comment: Yes, it's basically what I need, but it doesn't respect the margins of the ".description" if I change the size of the ".gallery" in specific cases. So it can happen that there are overlaps or too much space between the items.

Comment: @Anna_B check the updated

Comment: Woooow! How did you come up with this idea? Genius.

Comment: @Anna_B you issue is to be able to allow your images to shrink more so you have to remove the min-width restriction to allow them to shrink to 0 if needed

Comment: – I just also tried to implement videos, and now it doesn't work so well anymore: https://jsfiddle.net/e9kf42qx/
The container of the video is larger than the video. How can this be fixed? I added it to my initial question.

Comment: @Anna_B what kind of fix? the video behave the same as image but the object-fit won't render the same. maybe use `cover` for the videos

Comment: – I mean something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQZgK.png – The container of the video is taller than the video, but only until the bottom of the area. It looks pretty weird. So I wouldn't like to use cover, just to not extend the video container more than it's actual size. Maybe this image shows it better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaNtq.png

Answer (score -1):

Even though u explained its confusing.
From what i got from ur question is that u want to kept ur spaces between images.
Add **gap** property (flex objects gap b/w)

```
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  resize: both;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  gap:20px //Value change as per ur design.
}
```

you could also view "**justify-content**" property of flex

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the `max-width` from `.item`

```
.item {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
}
```

Comment: Basically yes, but then the width of an item doesn't adjust to the gallery size anymore.

Comment: @Anna_B no, you are not obliged to upvote a "wrong" answer. Voting is for content not persons. Being helpful doesn't immune anyone to the voting system that is used to curate the content.

Comment: Oh, wow! :D Sorry about that :D

Comment: This SO thing is becoming a religion.

Comment: @TemaniAfif  Nobody is asking to upvote a "wrong" answer.