# How can I preserve the height of an HTML video based on its content?

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video, sizing

This is my code:

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  resize: both;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item img,
.item video {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  min-width: 0;
}

.description {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="item">
    <video controls>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="description">Video</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Wald018.jpg/256px-Wald018.jpg">
    <div class="description">One</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg/256px-Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg">
    <div class="description">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg/297px-Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg">
    <div class="description">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is based on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673762/how-can-i-avoid-such-weird-spaces-in-a-horizontal-flexbox-gallery). It works well with images, and also seems to work well with videos. But if for example the ratio of the browser window changes, then the container of a HTML video is bigger than the actual video. You can see it here in an abstract way:
[image]

How can we let the video container always keep the size of the actual video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `align-items: center` to the `.items` class so that they aren't stretched, and then we can stretch it by adding `height: 100%` to the image and video selector then also add `max-width: none` to both `.items` and image and video selector, like this:

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  resize: both;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.item img,
.item video {
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}

.description {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="item">
    <video controls>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="description">Video</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Wald018.jpg/256px-Wald018.jpg">
    <div class="description">One</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg/256px-Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg">
    <div class="description">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg/297px-Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg">
    <div class="description">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## EDIT:

I couldn't think of a way of using pure CSS, so I thought of using a bit of javascript for this. Basically, we could "imitate" the video dimensions and add it to an `svg` element, then we can use that element as the source of the width/height for the video, then we can add the video on top of that `svg` element, like this:

```js
const gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery")[0].children

for (var i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
  if (gallery[i].getElementsByTagName("video").length > 0) {
    const originalVideo = gallery[i].getElementsByTagName("video")[0]

    originalVideo.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(e) {
      var width = this.videoWidth,
        height = this.videoHeight;
      const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
      svg.setAttribute("height", height)
      svg.setAttribute("width", width)
      const vidContainer = document.createElement('div')
      vidContainer.classList += 'video-container'
      const item = this.parentNode
      item.removeChild(this)
      vidContainer.appendChild(svg)
      vidContainer.appendChild(this)

      item.insertBefore(vidContainer, item.firstChild);
    }, false);
  }
}
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  resize: both;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  min-width: 0;
}

.description {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
}

.item svg {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.item video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="item">
    <video controls>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="description">Video</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Wald018.jpg/256px-Wald018.jpg">
    <div class="description">One</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg/256px-Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg">
    <div class="description">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg/297px-Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg">
    <div class="description">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then the items don't fit in the width as well.

Comment: @Anna_B I see, please check my edit on this answer

Answer (score 1):

## SOLUTION 1

This uses js to forcefully set the max-height so that the controls are resized

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0].style.width = "800px"
        })
        function widthCheck() {
if(document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0].style.width.split("p")[0] - 330 < document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0].style.height.split("p")[0]) { 
  
                document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].style.maxHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0].style.width.split("p")[0]/2 + "px"

                document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].style.marginTop = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].style.maxHeight.split("p")[0]/((document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0].style.width.split("p")[0]/document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0].style.height.split("p")[0])/0.8) + "px"
            } else {
                document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].style.maxHeight = "none"
                document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].style.marginTop = "0px"
            }
            if(document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0].style.width.split("p")[0] < 80) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0].style.width = "80px"
            }
        }
setInterval(widthCheck)
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  resize: both;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item img,
.item video {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  min-width: 0;
}

.description {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
        <div class="item">
          <video controls>
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
          <div class="description">Video</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Wald018.jpg/256px-Wald018.jpg">
          <div class="description">One</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg/256px-Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg">
          <div class="description">Two</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg/297px-Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg">
          <div class="description">Three</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I can provide an explanation if needed

## SOLUTION 2

you can also fix this is by setting the `object-fit` property in the css to `cover`. This won't change the size of the audio controls, instead will make the video adjust its size accordingly.

I will put the code snippet below for what I just said

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  resize: both;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item img,
.item video {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  min-width: 0;
}

.description {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
        <div class="item">
          <video controls>
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
          <div class="description">Video</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Wald018.jpg/256px-Wald018.jpg">
          <div class="description">One</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg/256px-Ung_norsk_furuskog_og_morgent%C3%A5ke.jpg">
          <div class="description">Two</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg/297px-Swedish_Spruce_Forest.jpg">
          <div class="description">Three</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Since we can't change the size of the audio controls, this is the only way.

Comment: This cuts off the media items in some cases

Comment: What cases are these? Kindly tell me so i can find a solution to reform my answer

Comment: Please change the width of ".gallery" to a smaller width, then you can see the items are cut off.

Comment: @Anna_B You could set the min-width and min-height of gallery to 80px and 30px respectively and the items won't be cut off. Hope that solves your problem. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: But the items get cropped. This must not happen.

Comment: I think i got what you're saying @Anna_B i think this time the solution will work
Solution 1 is the solution i put now, Solution 2 is the previous solution

Answer (score 1):

So that the video does not get cut off and does not lose its proportions, it is not necessary to stretch it. I would do something like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 220px;
  column-gap: 16px;
}

.item {
  flex: none;
  display: flex;
}

.gallery-video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery-video-bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(2px);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.gallery-video{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.item img {
  height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

.description {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="gallery-video-wrapper">
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" class="gallery-video-bg"></video>
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" class="gallery-video" controls></video>
    </div>
    <div class="description">Video</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/260/220">
    <div class="description">One</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/240">
    <div class="description">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/160/260">
    <div class="description">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. You can synchronize the background video using javascript.

Comment: Sorry, this does not help. The solution of that got completely lost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673762/how-can-i-avoid-such-weird-spaces-in-a-horizontal-flexbox-gallery

Comment: What exactly was lost?